# WCF REST tutorials for POX

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest, pox

Can anyone tell me where to find good WCF REST tutorials? using (POX)

[This one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395208.aspx) is ok but i want to use something a little simpler

I can't seem to find anything decent that uses webget/webinvoke attributes etc...

I don't want to use the REST Starter kit

Comment: You want to use WCF, but not the starter kit.  Do you want to use System.ServiceModel.Web?  What are the reasons behind your technology choices?  Why not use OpenRasta?

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial is REALLY simple. There is a screencast plus sourcecode. Great just to get you started with WCF REST.

http://www.michaelckennedy.net/blog/2009/03/24/RESTfulWebServicesWithWCFScreencast.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have been watching [WCF tutorials on pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2009/03/17/wcf-rest-screencasts-videos.aspx) and have found them to be very helpful.

Comment: Those are the same as on Channel 9 - Aaron Skonnard is a co-founder of Pluralsight. Indeed great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

The show [endpoint.tv](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/) on Channel9 had a plethora of screencast by Aaron Skonnard on using WCF - including a whole bunch of screencasts on using the REST features of WCF. Highly recommended! Check them out, well worth your time!

Marc

EDIT:

If you - for whatever reason - really cannot use the REST starter kit, you might want to look at the ADO.NET Data Services, as mentioned here: [Getting started with REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60477/getting-started-with-rest)

That's basically REST based on WCF, exposed as ATOM feeds.

Comment: these are using the rest starter kit though arent they?
i dont want to use that.

Comment: Why not? And if you don't use that, you really don't have the option of doing REST - WCF out of the box (without the REST starter kit) is really geared towards SOAP messaging - not REST.